# Защищает ли Касперский от уязвимостей Adobe Flash в браузере?

Tags: безопасность, kaspersky

Периодически появляются уязвимости в этом плагине. Если на каком-либо сайте будет стоять вредоносный код, как Касперский отреагирует на его действия? Сработает ли он на какие-либо подозрительные действия?

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю узнать можно или обратившись в тех. поддержку касперского или проверить на любом порно-сайте :)

Comment: Походу придется в поддержку обращаться.